# Error installing flatpak softwares "Unacceptable TLS certificate"

Tags: arch-linux, kde

I installed flatpak using

```
$ sudo pacman -S flatpak
```

after that i a added repo

```
$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

and it gives me error

```
"Unable to load summary from remote flathub: Unacceptable TLS certificate"
```

i added another following repo

```
$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

this got added without any error but if i install any software from flathub.org it gives me same previous error

```
"Unable to load summary from remote flathub: Unacceptable TLS certificate"
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it with the solution I found here, [Troubleshooting “Unacceptable TLS certificate” Error in Linux](https://itsfoss.com/unacceptable-tls-certificate-error-linux/):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

and then

```
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

You may need `sudo` or the `--user` flag for further flatpak operations, read here, Fedora-Remix-for-WS: [Flatpak support #81](https://github.com/WhitewaterFoundry/Fedora-Remix-for-WSL/issues/81).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your localtime, checked using `timedatectl`, is correct. To update it you can use:

```
sudo timedatectl set-ntp true
```